# Square-law based RBF kernel

Tags: activation-function

What is the Square-law based RBF kernel (SQ-RBF)? The definition in the table at the Wikipedia article [Activation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) looks wrong, since it says

```
y = 
     1 - x^2/2     for |x| <= 1
     2 - (2-x^2)/2 for 1 < |x| <= 2
     0             for |x| > 2
```

but this makes it discontinuous at x = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed quite odd. I can't really find many other sources on SQ-RBF, except [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=HR19DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=Square-law%20based%20RBF%20kernel&source=bl&ots=TtJd-5F_uV&sig=ACfU3U1ZFsPb1OSu-bFOO8Xtf12AqMzJ9g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHl5HR9rnlAhWQblAKHeeNByIQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Square-law%20based%20RBF%20kernel&f=false), where the definition differs from wikipedia, but when I plot this, it does not recover the image they show. However, if you define

```
y =
    1 - x^2/2        for |x| <= 1
    0.5*(|x|-2)^2    for 1 < |x| <= 2
    0                for |x| > 2
```

you can recover a sensible shape.